# Use a different launch screen for the first launch of an app

Tags: swift, xcode, load, launch, launch-screen

My current launch screen is exactly the same as what you see when the app loads (as recommended by Apple). However, the first time a user launches the app a video plays immediately following the launch screen - and the two are not identical at all.

Is there a way to change the launch screen for the first launch of the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously change the initial launch of the app either by changing the your `rootViewController` from `AppDelegate`

Put these lines of code in your AppDelegate

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = .white
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let mainViewController = YourMainViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = mainViewController

    return true
}
```